# 401 Invalid Authorization Error on Postman

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, authentication, gitlab, postman

I used an existing hris project, when I authenticated, it works fine and I got the token, but when I put the token on environment and used it for bearer authentication, it said invalid authorization, even though it works fine on my friend
[the access token] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/RdDz6.png)
[access token in environment] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/R556g.png)
[The Error, despite the same access token] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/jGktp.png)

I inputted the correct access token, it should've work